# Problem finding an element in an array - c++20

Tags: c++, arrays, c++20

I am trying to make a program to search for an element in an array. I imagine that this operation is very simple, but I have tried many solutions and every time there is a different error. Could anyone tell me where I'm wrong please? And what is the best way to find an element in an array? Thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string dec;
    string array[10] = {"111", "222", "333", "444"};
 
    dec = "333";
    if(find(array->begin(), array->end(), dec) != array->end())
    {
        cout << "\n" << dec << " found";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nnot found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Try `std::begin(array)`

Comment: @user14584436 [How do you figure?](https://godbolt.org/z/45f73KWGM). I also fixed your includes (you don't need `stdio.h` or `iterator` and `string.h` should be `string`, for `std::string`)

Comment: Have you set the compiler to use `C++20`?

Comment: `c_cpp_properties.json` is mostly for intellisense, how are you compiling the code? What does your `tasks.json` file look like?

Comment: @Bob__ thank you for the answer. This is my tasks.json file: https://pastebin.com/UVsdJHNe.

Comment: I see. Try adding `"-std=c++20"` to the `"args": [ ... ]` and then follow Alan's comment or look at the posted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `begin()` and `end()` for vectors.

You have to write it like below for arrays defined using `[]`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string dec;
    string array[10] = {"111", "222", "333", "444"};
 
    dec = "333";
    if(find(array, array + 10, dec) != (array + 10))
    {
        cout << "\n" << dec << " found";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nnot found";
    }
}
```

If you want to use vectors which is recommended as well in c++, you can change it to

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string dec;
    vector<string> array = {"111", "222", "333", "444"};

    dec = "333";
    if(find(array.begin(), array.end(), dec) != array.end())
    {
        cout << "\n" << dec << " found";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "\nnot found";
    }
}
```